# Unity2017で非同期処理が使えない

Tags: unity3d, websocket, 非同期

HoloLens(クライアント側)でwebsocket通信を利用しようとしています。  
他クライアントからサーバーへの接続を確認できたためHoloLens実機で接続テストしようとしたのですが、以下の部分の処理途中でアプリケーションが止まってしまっています。

```
    private void OnConnect() {
        AppendOutputLine("OnConnect");  
        messageWebSocket = new MessageWebSocket();
        messageWebSocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;
        messageWebSocket.MessageReceived += WebSock_MessageReceived;
        messageWebSocket.Closed += WebSock_Closed;
        Uri serverUri = new Uri("ws://192.168.11.2:1880");

        try {
            Task.Run(async () => {
                //Connect to the server.
                AppendOutputLine("Connect to the server..." + serverUri.ToString());

                await Task.Run(async () => {
                    AppendOutputLine("Task Run :" + serverUri.ToString());
                    await messageWebSocket.ConnectAsync(serverUri);
                    AppendOutputLine("ConnectAsync OK");

                    await WebSock_SendMessage(messageWebSocket, "Connect Start");
                });

                //AppendOutputLine("miss await Task");

            });


        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            AppendOutputLine("error : " + ex.ToString());

            //Add code here to handle any exceptions
        }
```

具体的には、"Connect to the server... ws://192.168.11.2:1880"が表示された段階でアプリケーションが止まり、その後の `await Task.Run(async () => {});` が実行できていません。  
Unityの
Scripting Runtime Version を Experimental(.NET 4.6 Equivalent)に、
Api Compatibility Level を .NET 4.6 に
変更したのですが、状況は変わりませんでした。

もし分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、解決方法を教えて頂きたいです。

環境
Unity2017.4.17f1
VisualStudio2017
Hololens OSbuild:10.0.17763.316

ソースコードは[この記事](https://www.1ft-seabass.jp/memo/2017/04/06/hololens_websocket_node-red_firstcontact/)を参考にしています。

以下、ソースコード全文

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using WebSocketSharp; // Unity
using WebSocketSharp.Net;
#else
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
#endif



public class WebSocketController : MonoBehaviour {

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    WebSocket ws;
#else
    private MessageWebSocket messageWebSocket;
    private DataWriter messageWriter;
    private bool busy;
#endif

    private Text targetText;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        this.targetText = this.GetComponent<Text>();

        this.targetText.text = "Start";

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        this.targetText.text = "Unity_Editor";
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.11.2:1880");
        var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        ws.OnOpen += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("WebSocket Open");
        };

        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("WebSocket Receive message: " + e.Data);

            // Main threadで実行
            context.Post(state => {
                this.targetText.text = state.ToString();
                }, e.Data);



        };

        ws.OnError += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("WebSocket Error Message: " + e.Message);
        };

        ws.OnClose += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("WebSocket Close");
        };

        ws.Connect();
#else   
        // HoloLens実機でWebSocket接続開始
        this.targetText.text = "Unity_UWP";
        OnConnect();

#endif

    }



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        //if (Input.GetKeyUp("s")) {
        //    ws.Send("Test Message");
        //}
#else   

#endif  
    }


#if UNITY_EDITOR
    void OnDestroy() {
        ws.Close();
        ws = null;
    }

#else
    private void OnConnect() {

        AppendOutputLine("OnConnect");

        messageWebSocket = new MessageWebSocket();

        //In this case we will be sending/receiving a string so we need to set the MessageType to Utf8.
        messageWebSocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;

        //Add the MessageReceived event handler.
        messageWebSocket.MessageReceived += WebSock_MessageReceived;

        //Add the Closed event handler.
        messageWebSocket.Closed += WebSock_Closed;

        // Uri serverUri = new Uri("ws://192.168.11.2:1880/testws"); // 別PCのNode-REDのWebSocketにつながる
        Uri serverUri = new Uri("ws://192.168.11.2:1880");


        try {
            Task.Run(async () => {
                //Connect to the server.
                AppendOutputLine("Connect to the server..." + serverUri.ToString());

                await Task.Run(async () => {
                    AppendOutputLine("Task Run :" + serverUri.ToString());
                    await messageWebSocket.ConnectAsync(serverUri);
                    AppendOutputLine("ConnectAsync OK");

                    await WebSock_SendMessage(messageWebSocket, "Connect Start");
                });

                //AppendOutputLine("miss await Task");

            });


        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            AppendOutputLine("error : " + ex.ToString());

            //Add code here to handle any exceptions
        }


    }

    private async Task WebSock_SendMessage(MessageWebSocket webSock, string message) {
        AppendOutputLine("WebSock_SendMessage : " + message);

        DataWriter messageWriter = new DataWriter(webSock.OutputStream);
        messageWriter.WriteString(message);
        await messageWriter.StoreAsync();
    }

    private void WebSock_MessageReceived(MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args) {
        DataReader messageReader = args.GetDataReader();
        messageReader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
        string messageString = messageReader.ReadString(messageReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
        AppendOutputLine("messageString : " + messageString);

        //Add code here to do something with the string that is received.

        Task.Run(async () => {

            UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnAppThread(() => {

                AppendOutputLine("InvokeOnAppThread : iTween");

                this.targetText.text = messageString;

            }, true);

            await Task.Delay(100);
        });
    }

    private void WebSock_Closed(IWebSocket sender, WebSocketClosedEventArgs args)
    {
        //Add code here to do something when the connection is closed locally or by the server
    }

    private void AppendOutputLine(string value)
    {
        // OutputField.Text += value + "\r\n";
        //Debug.Log(value);
        this.targetText.text = value;
    }

#endif

}
```